# Ambiguous call expression in Typescript

Tags: typescript

The following snippet creates an Ambiguous call expression error:

```
/// <reference path="typings/google.maps.d.ts" />
class GoogleMap {
    private geocoder;
    private latlng;

    constructor() {
        this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        this.latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.165691, 10.451526000000058);
    }
    private setElements(): void {
        this.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': "Berlin", 'latLng': this.latlng }, (results) => {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address); // 'Ambiguous call expression - could not choose overload'
        })
    }
```

`setContent(...)` has 2 overloads and the compiler cannot solve the correct type even though the type of `formatted_address` is solved correctly as string.  However it works when I set the type of the method parameter explicit:

```
var content: string = results[0].formatted_address;
infowindow.setContent(content);
```

Also a strange point: I figured that this workaround is not neccessary when I declare  `infoWindow` as class variable.

For me it looks like a bug, or do I miss something?

Comment: This isn't enough information. Post your `InfoWindow` class code

Comment: This class belongs to the Google Maps Api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow

Comment: Where did you get a `.d.ts` or is there a native TypeScript class somewhere?

Comment: I am using the google.maps.d.ts and I am pretty sure that I included it via NuGet. Do you think it is an issue with this file?

Comment: Please can you add the declaration for `infowindow.setContent` to your question so we can try it out?

Comment: I extended the example. You can copy-paste it and it should show you the error. The file google.maps.d.ts is available at NuGet. By the way: When I created this minimal example I figured that this error doesn't come up when `geocoder` is initialized on class level (so not in the constructor).

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see, in your d.ts file for the API, the geocode's callback function parameter seems to have it's type definition missing, if this is the case, TypeScript by default defines it's type as "any" and anything inner this object is defined of type "any" as well.

Therefore when you are calling

```
infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
```

TypeScript is looking for a function with the next signature:

```
setContent(param1: any);
```

Which is not defined in your d.ts file and as the type "any" can be any type, that's probably the reason you are getting this error.